Value error not showing the result expected to send result to telegram group
Im trying to send all my trade signal to my telegram group but I'm encountering the following error message:
enter image description here
import requests
import datetime

# Assuming 'trades_CL' is a list of tuples containing (signal, time, price, ticker_symbol)
prev_signal = None  # Initialize prev_signal
for trade in trades_CL:
    signal = trades_CL['Entry_Type']
    DateTime = trades_CL['Entry_Date']
    Price = trades_CL['Entry_Price']
    # Check if there's a change in signal
    if signal != prev_signal:
        if signal == 'Buy':
            message = f"{signal} signal for CRUDE OIL on {DateTime} at {Price}"
            base_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text={message}"
            requests.get(base_url)
            position = 'Long'

        elif signal == 'Sell':
            message = f"Sell signal for Crude OIL on {DateTime} with price {Price}"
            base_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text={message}"
            requests.get(base_url)
            position = 'Short'

        prev_signal = signal

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 11
      9 Price = trades_CL['Entry_Price']
     10 # Check if there's a change in signal
---> 11 if signal != prev_signal:
     12     if signal == 'Buy':
     13         message = f"{signal} signal for CRUDE OIL on {DateTime} at {Price}"

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().


May I know why this error happens? writing this to trigger buy and sell signal to my group. Any help is appreciated.
